# Changing sequence function from foldr to recursive function

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to get my head around the sequence function. I thought it may help if I wrote it as a recursive function but I am at a bit of a loss how to do it considering it is a monadic expression which I find somewhat difficult to convert to recursive. I mean what do you do with return (x:xs)? In other words I want to write the function without foldr. I have included two definitions below:

```
sequence _ = foldr k (return [])
              where
                k m m' = do { x <- m; xs <- m'; return (x:xs) }

sequence' _ = foldr k (return [])
               where
                  k m m' = m >>=
                          (\fstr -> m'>>=
                           (\rstr -> return (fstr:rstr)))
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: How do I write the function without foldr?

Comment: Don't write functions without me. :(

Answer (score 3):

One way to write `sequence` is simply `traverse id`, and I would encourage you to explore the relationship between `Traversable` and `Applicative` for deeper understanding.

I think what you're looking for is this definition:

```
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
sequence [] = return []
sequence (x:xs) = do
  x' <- x
  xs' <- sequence xs
  return (x':xs')
```

Comment: Ok. Will check out Traversable. That was what I was looking for.